# Python hazmat danger

Tags: openssl, audit, python

Is hazmat considered to be *secure*?

Here is a quote [from their docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/):

> This is a “Hazardous Materials” module. You should ONLY use it if you’re 100% absolutely sure that you know what you’re doing because this module is full of land mines, dragons, and dinosaurs with laser guns.

This is confusing, since there is no further explanation on that. If this statement refers to IT-security, then it's interesting that [even google is using this](https://github.com/google/grr/blob/38278e2e57e7486eed418493b1b32748ff10ccfa/grr/server/grr_response_server/key_utils.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you cite means only that the "average" user which has no deeper understanding of cryptography should only use the higher level cryptographic functionality. The cryptographic primitives should only be used by somebody with a deeper understanding of cryptography. Without such understanding it is easy to make serious mistakes leading to insecure software and don't even realize that these are mistakes.